# Does order of fields matter on a resume or LinkedIn?

Tags: software-industry, resume, skills, job-description, customer-service

Is it normal to show education and volunteering field first, and then work experience on a resume, LinkedIn or cover letter?

The reason is that I don't have much relevant work experience for a Helpdesk computer job as I used to work in a warehouse as a general worker, but my academic record is great, like my CGPA 4.26 / 4.33 with many projects.

Also, I did volunteering as a customer representative, which looks better for a help desk job as compared to warehouse general worker.

Comment: [Might be slightly relevant to consider as well](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/66754/order-of-the-cv)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You build your resume to show your strengths for the job you are applying for. This could be showing off your education first, if it's your strongest point and most relevant to the job, or showing off other stuff.

In the end, you are trying to sell yourself, it doesn't matter which order things come in as long as you can provide all relevant information and you can grab the person's attention.

You shouldn't ask, "What's normal?", but instead ask, "What shows me in the best light for the job I'm applying for?". If this means putting your work experience at the bottom of the CV, then put it at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Providing your resume through services like LinkedIn or InDeed are a great option for getting your material out quickly, and to a broad number of potential employers.

The format of your fields will have a direct impact on your evaluation by resume reviewers.Before simply submitting a generic application, do some follow up on the company's website for additional information on the position. Look to see if they have a downloadable application for their open positions, and curtail your response to their required criteria.

Submission of a  personalized resume will give you the best opportunity to frame your relevant work and volunteer experience, but anything included should be DIRECTLY relevant.(there are several other posts on resume creation, so please refer to those for the best method of making your argument as the right candidate)

The organization I work for frequently uses services like InDeed and LinkedIn to bring in large numbers of applications for positions. The ones that stand out typically provide relevant experience, and correspond with an already received copy of our company's own application.